# Automatically Saving Excel Workbook into another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to macros and I was wondering if there was a way to auto save an excel workbook into another workbook, overwriting the data. Like if the file is located in different folder. It would automatically save that workbook to a new location every time data was changed. Also, how to avoid seeing message `Are you sure you want to overwrite this file?`

Comment: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` will make it automatically overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

The [Workbook SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel) command will help you a lot. Combine that with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

Make sure you put this in either a function or an [Excel button](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLWRqGGdGEQ).

Comment: Can you do this automatically. No keys pressed. Like if someone finishes making changes to excel file and saves it, once that button was pressed, can it also save into another workbook with the same name just in a different folder or directory

Comment: You can do something like that by adding code to a [Workbook event](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/3/31/run-vba-macros-when-a-spreadsheet-opens-or-closes) (Such as closing the notebook)